# How to send signal to particular instance along with details?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, bpmn

I have 2 process P and Q where I am trying to throw signal (globally)from process P and catching signal at Q. When there are multiple instances, for example: In process P -process instances P1, P2 and in process Q -process instances Q1 and Q2. 
If I throw signal from one process instance that will be caught by multiple instances of other process.

For example, If I throw signal from Q1 that will be caught by all the instances of P [P1,P2].

**I tried following ways:**

1] RuntimeService.signalEventReceived(String signalName, String executionId);

With this method, I can invoke particular instance but, was not able to pass the details[data].

2] 
POST runtime/signals
{
"signalName": "My Signal",
"tenantId" : "execute",
"async": true,
"variables": [
{"name": "testVar", "value": "This is a string"}

]
}

With this api, I was able to get details[data] by passing variables, but was not able to invoke particular process instance.

Is there any way to send signal to particular instance along with details?

Thanks & Regards,

Shilpa V Kulkarni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use this method

```
void signalEventReceived(String signalName, String executionId, Map<String, Object> processVariables);
```

Comment: does anybody have an idea why it takes 2 seconds to conitnue (activiti 6 in use, the flow continue up to parallel gateway which acts as threads join, there is no extra logic!) ? also why async method does not accept processVariables map?